# DataTables does not display data from elasticsearch results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, elasticsearch, datatable

I am trying to run functions from an elasticsearch instance through to datatables to display results.
But the problem is that I cannot display it in datatable

```
<head>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.8/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.8/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.8/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.6/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.8/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/elasticsearch/10.0.1/elasticsearch.min.js"></script>


<script>
  var client = elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'localhost:9200'
});

$('#example').dataTable( {
'columns': [
    { 'sTitle': 'timestamp', 'sName': 'timestamp' },
    { 'sTitle': 'message', 'sName': 'message' }
],
'bProcessing': true,
'bServerSide': true,
'fnServerData': $.fn.dataTable.elastic_datatables( {
   index: 'logstash-log-*',
   type: 'log',
   client: client,
   body: {
    query: {
      "bool": {
        "must": [{
                "term": {
                "user": <?php echo $user;>
                        }
              },
             {
               "range": {
                 "timestamp": {
                            "from":<?php echo $from;>,
                             "to":<?php echo $to;>
                             }
                        }
            },
           {
           "query_string": {
                   "default_field": "_all",    
                    "query": "*"
                         }
             }
          ]}
       }
     }
  } )
 } );

</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <thead>
   <tr>
      <th ></th>
        <th >timestamp</th>
         <th >message</th>
         </tr>
              </thead>
              <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <th></th>
                  <th>timestamp</th>
                  <th>message</th>
                </tr>
              </tfoot>
            </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is the package using for jquery.elastic-datatables.js https://github.com/pidupuis/elastic-datatables
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: from DataTables debugger,didn't got any error

Comment: via Chrome Developer Tool (F12) got "Uncaught ReferenceError: elasticsearch is not defined" error and Cannot set property 'elastic_datatables' of undefined error

Comment: Check the network tab for elasticsearch.min.js. Is it getting loaded successfully.

Comment: php end tags missing `?>` plus there's no `</script>` tag